# Использование переменной в параметре вызова

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Можно ли как то в опциях вызова функции использовать переменную?
пример. Есть список вопросов для теста. В начале функции каждого вопроса я создаю переменную q_num = 5. для пятого вопроса. Эта переменная много где используется в самой функции, что сильно упрощает создание новых вопросов путём копирования. Нужно только заменить значение переменной. Все ответы записываются в FSM, и вот тут затык.
В теле функции ошибки искать не нужно, даже если они там кажется что есть, это вырванный из контекста кусок просто для понимания

```
class TestsState(StatesGroup):
    question = State()
    question1 = State()
    question2 = State()
    question3 = State()
    question4 = State()
    question5 = State()
    question6 = State()

@router.callback_query(CallbackFactoryOficianTest.filter(F.action == "qo5"))
async def answer(call: types.CallbackQuery, bot: Bot, callback_data: CallbackFactoryOficianTest, state: FSMContext):
    q_num = 5
    await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
    data = await state.get_data()
    ans = int(callback_data.ans)
    qwestion = data['question']
    answer = data[f'question{callback_data.number}'][ans - 1][0]
    await state.update_data(question5=f'{qwestion} \n {answer}\n' +
                                              (' <b>верно</b>' if callback_data.value == '1' else ' <b>ошибка</b>'))
    await state.update_data(question5=list_buts)
```

Есть ли какая то формулировка записи, что бы мне в каждом вопросе не менять параметр стейта, а так же сделать через переменную? Вопрос вот по этой строчке кода

```
await state.update_data(question5=list_buts)
```

Comment: Без кода, где эта переменная используется, и без кода вызываемого метода, не очень понятна суть

Comment: Дак по сути не важен код, это касается параметров любой функции. Можно ли в параметр встроить переменную? Вот ключевой вопрос. Но если прям поможет сейчас допишу что то что бы было понятнее

Comment: ваша ``q_num``, которая равна 5, в коде нигде не используется

Comment: Дак да, в том и вопрос - я хочу её применить и спрашиваю как! я не хочу писать question5, хочу что бы было question5{q_num}, но так не работает. Вопрос - есть ли варианты как это можно заставить работать?

Comment: question[num] = State() не вариант ?

Comment: Да, вот проще всего из `question` сделать словарь или список и обращаться к этой коллекции по нужному номеру, а не плодить однотипные переменные с номерами. Тогда этот номер можно будет хоть напрямую использовать, хоть в функцию передать.

Comment: Можно еще так `await state.update_data({"question5": list_buts})`

Comment: Не получается реализовать ни один из вариантов. Я не понимаю как в class TestsState(StatesGroup): засунуть список состояний не через перечисление. Покажите пример пожалуйста. Гугл ответов не даёт, там все примеры из 3х-4х состояний и они все разные, а про однотипные примеров найти не могу, что бы через словарь делалось или как то ещё

Answer (score 0):

```
def fun(q): # функция с использованием переменной
    print(q)

fun(3) # вызов функции с числом

n = 5
fun(n) # вызов функции с переменной, равной 5
```

Comment: Вопрос не про переменную, а именно про параметр. Как вызывать с переменной я понимаю.

Comment: а что такое параметр?

Comment: это когда ты пишешь не print("1шт "), а print(1, end="шт "). В данной случае 1 можно поменять на любую переменную и в конце всегда будет дописываться шт

Comment: именно это я и написал в ответе. Даже исправил сейчас, чтобы вам понятнее стало

Comment: print(q, end="шт ") по q нет у меня вопроса. У меня вопрос по end

Comment: так совсем непонятно какой вопрос